# Bash - search directory for all scripts

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to search a directory (and all subdirectories) for all scripts and write them out with full path and type of script. the output should look like this:

```
/home/student/scripts/find.sh bash
/home/student/scripts/bin/server.pl perl
/home/student/scripts/bin/client.pl perl
```

I know that i should use find, then head and grep to determine the type of script, but I am really bad at bash, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close to what you're trying to get:

```
find /home/student/scripts -type f -name "*.*" -exec file '{}' +
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code does not do what I need, it doesnt write out anything.